# OSError: libopenslide.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am struggling to resolve an error I'm facing while importing openslide, and while I understand the meaning of the error broadly, I am still not sure how to resolve it.
This is the traceback of the error:

```
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openslide
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/h/329/keerat/anaconda3/envs/clam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openslide/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openslide import lowlevel
  File "/h/329/keerat/anaconda3/envs/clam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openslide/lowlevel.py", line 84, in <module>
    _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenslide.so.0')
  File "/h/329/keerat/anaconda3/envs/clam/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/h/329/keerat/anaconda3/envs/clam/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libopenslide.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here's the remote server details:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Since I'm on a remote server, I do not have the permission to run `sudo ldconfig -v` to diagnose the issue, unlike what most solutions on the internet recommend.

I checked, openslide is already installed in my conda environment.

```
$ conda list openslide
# packages in environment at xxx/anaconda3/envs/env_name:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
openslide-python          1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I also tried:

1. Reinstalling the package
2. Downloading into pseudo root directory and then installing package as mentioned [here](https://blog.davidassigbi.com/how-to-install-on-linux-without-root-privileges)
   but doesn't help. Any guidance will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The openslide Python library wraps the openslide C library, which means you have to have the C library installed before the Python library can be used. `conda list` only tells you about the Python library; `conda` doesn't know anything about which C libraries are present.

Comment: According to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopenslide0, you should use `sudo apt-get install libopenslide0` to get the C library installed on Bionic.

Comment: (btw, if instead of Conda you were using Nix, you'd have a single package manager that understands both Python and C libraries and otherwise generally spans languages; asking Nix to give you, say, `python311.withPackages (p: [p.openslide p.numpy])` will give you a Python 3.11 installation with openslide, numpy, _and all the C libraries they depend on_).